# laravel php 7 consumes ram

Tags: php, apache, laravel

-short version : When I run "php artisan serve " computer freezes and needs a restart."php 7" using all the ram.what should I do?

-detailed explanation : I created a project with **Laravel** and put in a lot of work and it worked fine till yesterday ,today I've changed a few lines on some *views* (**no config** files were touched) and when I ran **"php artisan serve"** and opened browser to see the changes my computer got slow and eventually froze completely .I've checked my system resources and saw "**php 7**" was consuming all of my **ram** and swap and browser couldn't load the page.
I've checked and my other projects work fine.the problem occures only on this one.
I have HPprobook and 4GiB ram ,10GiB swap memory,using **Laravel 5.4** and **PHP7** .My  OS is a  freshly installed **Ubuntu 17.4** and using **apache 2** as a web server.

I've restarted apache2 ,updated composer packages,dumped autoload but as I expected no effect.

Any one has any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

If you want small ram footprint instead of using `php artisan serve` You can install valet for ubuntu

P.S `php artisan serve` does not need apache you can try to stop it

Comment: didn't know the P.S. part , tnx.